# How do I update the value of void** in other function, and save it to another?

Tags: c++11, pointers, reference

If I have a code for example like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void swap(void** a) {
    int tmp = 5;
    void* b = &tmp;
    a = &b;
}

int main()
{
    int x=11;
   void* y=&x;
   void** z=&y;
   swap(z);
   void* a = *z;
   cout << *(int*)a << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

The code above prints 11, but I want to update the value of z (its address) to point to a place so I can print 5 (I mean update it). What should I do so that when I send z to the function and get back to main I can receive 5 instead of 11.

I'm just not that good with pointers.

EDIT: I must send to swap an argument with `void**`

Answer (score 1):

You can't update the value of a `void**` (i.e. what it points to) by passing it to a function that takes a `void**`. That only allows to modify the pointed-to memory, not what address the pointer you pass to the function points to.

To update what it points to, the parameter should be a `void**&` or a `void***`.

Regardless of what solution you choose, the code you posted is extremely error prone and a hell to maintain. You should totally avoid it.

Also, note that `&tmp` becomes invalid as long as you exit the function, because the local variable `tmp` gets destroyed.